# Generic Parameter inferred to be unknown

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I found some posts and github issues while searching for "Generic Parameter inferred to be unknown" but my skill level doesn't seem high enough for me to understand the issue at all.

Here is my code ([playground](https://tsplay.dev/wQJJvN)):

```js
function createFun<T>(arg: (f: (id: T) => T) => T) {
  // body of this doesn't matter
}

const fun1 = createFun((f) => f(1)); // T is inferred to be unknown
const fun2 = createFun((f) => f("")); // T is inferred to be unknown
const fun3 = createFun((f) => f(true)); // T is inferred to be unknown

// Question:

// can createFun be modified such that the above is inferred as

//   * createFun<number>((f) => f(1));
//   * createFun<string>((f) => f(""));
//   * createFun<boolean>((f) => f(true));

// ?
```

Is it possible to modify `createFun` such that the generic parameter `T` is inferred correctly?

I wonder, because

```js
createFun<string>((f) => f(1));
```

raises an error (as it should) while

```js
createFun<number>((f) => f(1));
```

doesn't (as it should).

So Typescript has clearly enough information to infer `T` properly?

Comment: `function createFun<T>(callback: (f: <Z>(id: Z) => Z) => T)` works idk

Comment: Interesting & Thanks. I made a new [playground](https://tsplay.dev/N5kkMW) showing that this does not satisfy the initial constraint but maybe I can augment this with some "T must equal Z" constraints. I'll try. ^^

Comment: I failed with my attempt. :x

Comment: Pretty sure this is just a design limitation of TypeScript (see [this comment on ms/TS#54438](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/54438#issuecomment-1566347281)); when in doubt, annotate or specify types.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I understand your linked comment. This just makes me really sad because as far as I understand TS could technically infer correctly but refuses to do so. (performance reasons?)

Comment: Yes, you can write an answer, if you like. (:

Comment: “Refuses to do so” is a strange characterization. The current inference system has very good inference behavior for *partially-written* code, and the theoretically “correct” unification algorithms tend not to.  It would also take a huge amount of effort to try to implement such algorithms, so it has yet to be worth it for the TS team.  There might be some incremental improvement that adds support for what you’re trying to do, but your use case isn’t very common so I wouldn’t expect the language to change drastically to handle it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently a design limitation of TypeScript, see [microsoft/TypeScript#47599](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47599).

When you call `createFun(f => f(1));`, the callback argument `f => f(1)` is *context-sensitive*; the type of `f` has to be inferred [contextually](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) from the type of the `arg` parameter for the function.  But `createFun` is a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function, with a type parameter `T` whose type has to be inferred from the type of the callback argument.  So the type of the callback argument depends on the type of the function parameter which depends on the type of the callback argument. That circularity of dependencies often leads to inference failure, where the compiler defers inference of one piece until after it infers the other piece, at which point information is lost and things fall back to `unknown` or `any`.

There have been incremental improvements in TypeScript to deal with situations where *pieces* of an argument depend on other pieces of the argument, like object properties that depend on other object properties, as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#48538](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/48538), but so far nothing when a single context-sensitive function's input type depends on itself directly.  I don't know if this will ever be supported or not; one might possibly add a comment to microsoft/TypeScript#47599 or file a new issue. But my suspicion is that it's not high on anyone's priority list, especially since the workaround is so simple: just manually specify the type parameter:

```
const fun1 = createFun<number>((f) => f(1)); // easiest
```

Or break the knot in any number of ways:

```
type IdFunc<T> = (id: T) => T;    
function createFun<T>(arg: (f: IdFunc<T>) => T) {}


const fun2 = createFun((f: IdFunc<string>) => f("")); // harder 
const fun3 = createFun<boolean>((f: IdFunc<boolean>): boolean => f(true)); // extreme
```

---

Note that it's technically possible for TypeScript's inference algorithm to be completely rewritten to use a so-called *full [unification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_(computer_science)) algorithm*, as discussed in [microsoft/TypeScript#30134](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30134).  Some functional programming languages have full unification, and it can be proven that they infer types "properly".

TypeScript is unlikely ever to do this, though.  First, it would be a huge amount of effort to replace the inference algorithms.  Even if they put in such effort, it might make developer experience worse: see [this comment on microsoft/TypeScript#17520](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17520#issuecomment-318935065):

> [TypeScript's inference algorithm] differs from the unification based type inference implemented by some functional programming languages, but it has the distinct advantage of being able to make partial inferences in incomplete code which is hugely beneficial to statement completion in IDEs.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgJgMQK4DsDGAeAKgPigXigAoBLOALiiwEoC8sBuAKCYDNU1gSB7FKNAE4QAhsAjIU2HEWECA5pSKtK8CZly189WgG8mUKAHpDUAEbc4IKN1ZRgACxIBnKHG4QnKAOTAoAW1ExASYAXxYmNF4nX3YUAEYCfiFRcVQMFCQ-UwgBaSVNPFYiOOpqBiMTEScSD2AIqJjUACZEwRExCSIlFUQODGiBEhQ5HAKoIoAiCdLy4yh7WTgcqHqUaPHUAGZW5I60824AGxEUPOVYXvQMA+PhU+pKG5O6caJgASQIGYqoCAAPd4QPwQJhAA)

Comment: I didn't think about the "type inference on incomplete code" problem. This is the first and only argument I ever heard why complete inference is not supported / most likely will be never supported. Overall nice write up with links to relevant issues and the unification algorithm (didn't know that). As always +1